# Printing all different triplets in list with nested loops in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to write a function `PrintTriplets(n)` in Python3 that takes in input an integer and prints all the possible triplets of numbers from 0 to n-1 without repetition.
I wanted to do it with three nested for loops as follows:

```
 def NewTrip(n):
     for i in range(n-2):
            for j in range(i+1,n-1):
                    for k in range(i+j+1,n):
                            print([i,j,k])
```

Interestingly this function does not behave as I expected. For example if `n=4` the output is

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 3]
```

Therefore it does not print the triple `[1,2,3]`. For every value of n I tried, a large number of triples is not printed.

I feel that I am missing something really fundamental about nested foor loops. Any help will be very much aprecciated!

Comment: print the values at each level. the range k is empty for i=1

Comment: @azro thanks for the comment! However I still don't get it.  Why the range k is empty for i=1?

Comment: shouldn't the innermost loop start from `j+1`?

Comment: ahhhhh! Right!!!

Comment: I feel like an idiot... thanks a lot!